# User has many computers, computers have many attributes in different tables, best way to JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I have a table for users:

```
USERS:
ID   |   NAME  | 
----------------
1    |   JOHN  |
2    |   STEVE |
```

a table for computers:

```
COMPUTERS:
ID   |   USER_ID |
------------------
13   |     1     |
14   |     1     |
```

a table for processors:

```
PROCESSORS:
ID   |   NAME             |
---------------------------
27   |   PROCESSOR TYPE 1 |
28   |   PROCESSOR TYPE 2 |
```

and a table for harddrives:

```
HARDDRIVES:
ID   |   NAME              |
---------------------------|
35   |   HARDDRIVE TYPE 25 |
36   |   HARDDRIVE TYPE 90 |
```

Each computer can have many attributes from the different attributes tables (processors, harddrives etc), so I have intersection tables like this, to link the  attributes to the computers:

```
COMPUTER_PROCESSORS:
C_ID |  P_ID  |
--------------|
13   |   27   |
13   |   28   |
14   |   27   |

COMPUTER_HARDDRIVES:
C_ID |  H_ID  |
--------------|
13   |   35   |
```

So user JOHN, with id 1 owns computer 13 and 14. Computer 13 has processor 27 and 28, and computer 13 has harddrive 35. Computer 14 has processor 27 and no harddrive.

Given a user's id, I would like to retrieve a list of that user's computers with each computers attributes.

I have figured out a query that gives me a somewhat of a result:

```
SELECT computers.id, processors.id AS p_id, processors.name AS p_name, harddrives.id AS h_id, harddrives.name AS h_name,
FROM computers

JOIN computer_processors ON (computer_processors.c_id = computers.id) 
JOIN processors ON (processors.id = computer_processors.p_id)

JOIN computer_harddrives ON (computer_harddrives.c_id = computers.id) 
JOIN harddrives ON (harddrives.id = computer_harddrives.h_id)

WHERE computers.user_id = 1
```

Result:

```
ID   | P_ID | P_NAME           | H_ID | H_NAME            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
13   |  27  | PROCESSOR TYPE 1 |  35  | HARDDRIVE TYPE 25 |
13   |  28  | PROCESSOR TYPE 2 |  35  | HARDDRIVE TYPE 25 |
```

But this has several problems...

1. Computer 14 doesnt show up, because it has no harddrive.
   **Can I somehow make an OUTER JOIN to make sure that all computers show up, even if there a some attributes they don't have?**
2. Computer 13 shows up twice, with the same harddrive listet for both. When more attributes are added to a computer (like 3 blocks of ram), the number of rows returned for that computer gets pretty big, and it makes it had to sort the result out in application code. **Can I somehow make a query, that groups the two returned rows together? Or a query that returns NULL in the h_name column in the second row, so that all values returned are unique?**

EDIT:
What I would like to return is something like this:

```
ID   | P_ID | P_NAME           | H_ID | H_NAME            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
13   |  27  | PROCESSOR TYPE 1 |  35  | HARDDRIVE TYPE 25 |
13   |  28  | PROCESSOR TYPE 2 |  35  | NULL              |
14   |  27  | PROCESSOR TYPE 1 | NULL | NULL              |
```

Or whatever result that make it easy to turn it into an array like this

```
[13] =>
    [P_NAME] =>
         [0] => PROCESSOR TYPE 1
         [1] => PROCESSOR TYPE 2
    [H_NAME] =>
         [0] => HARDDRIVE TYPE 25


[14] =>
    [P_NAME] =>
         [0] => PROCESSOR TYPE 1
```

Comment: how do you link computers,processors and harddrives tables as i dont see any common column

Comment: can you display the final result that you wanted to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. The two joins are different from each other. The `INNER JOIN` (*which you are currently using*) only returns the records which both has at least one match on either side of the table. And that is why `computer 14` won't should because it has no match on table `COMPUTER_HARDDRIVES`. `LEFT JOIN` on the other hand, returns all records on the *left hand side* table whether it no match on the other side of the tables.

```
SELECT  a.ID AS UserID,
        a.Name as UserName,
        b.ID as ComputerID,
        d.ID as ProcessorID,
        d.Name as ProcessorName,
        f.ID as HardDriveID,
        f.name as HardDriveName
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN computers b
            ON a.ID = b.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN computer_processors c
            ON b.ID = c.C_ID
        LEFT JOIN PROCESSORS d
            ON c.p_ID = d.ID
        LEFT JOIN COMPUTER_HARDDRIVES e
            ON b.ID = e.c_ID
        LEFT JOIN HARDDRIVE f
            ON e.h_ID = f.ID
WHERE   a.ID = 1
```

- [***See SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2ab6/1)
- for more details about joins, see [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

and since you want to groupt the rows together, youcan take advantage of `GROUP_CONCAT()` function. basically, what it does is it combines the value of the columns into comma separated value

```
SELECT  a.ID AS UserID,
        a.Name as UserName,
        b.ID as ComputerID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.ID) as ProcessorID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.Name) as ProcessorName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.ID) as HardDriveID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.name) as HardDriveName
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN computers b
            ON a.ID = b.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN computer_processors c
            ON b.ID = c.C_ID
        LEFT JOIN PROCESSORS d
            ON c.p_ID = d.ID
        LEFT JOIN COMPUTER_HARDDRIVES e
            ON b.ID = e.c_ID
        LEFT JOIN HARDDRIVE f
            ON e.h_ID = f.ID
WHERE   a.ID = 1
GROUP BY UserID, UserName, ComputerID
```

- [***See SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bca8/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, both approaches work beautifully! I'm a litte worried about the GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT...) though, since it uses a comma to separate the values, and some of the values in my columns can potentially already have a comma (like 'processor type 25, xx'), and then it will be very hard to sort from there. I think I will go with the first approach and then sort everything in application code. Which one of the approaches would you choose?

Comment: actually you don't have to worry about the separator because you can change it and you can also sort it inside `group_concat`. [*Click here for demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bca8/2).

Comment: [SQL Fiddle Demo (GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER BY and SEPARATOR change)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bca8/5)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT computers.id, 
       group_concat(distinct processors.id) AS p_ids, 
       group_concat(distinct processors.name) AS p_names, 
       group_concat(distinct harddrives.id) AS h_ids, 
       group_concat(distinct harddrives.name) AS h_names
FROM computers
JOIN computer_processors ON (computer_processors.c_id = computers.id) 
JOIN processors ON (processors.id = computer_processors.p_id)
LEFT JOIN computer_harddrives ON (computer_harddrives.c_id = computers.id) 
LEFT JOIN harddrives ON (harddrives.id = computer_harddrives.h_id)
WHERE computers.user_id = 1
group by computers.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT computers.id, processors.id AS p_id, processors.name AS p_name, harddrives.id AS h_id, harddrives.name AS h_name
FROM computers

LEFT JOIN computer_processors ON (computer_processors.c_id = computers.id) 
LEFT JOIN processors ON (processors.id = computer_processors.p_id)

LEFT JOIN computer_harddrives ON (computer_harddrives.c_id = computers.id) 
LEFT JOIN harddrives ON (harddrives.id = computer_harddrives.h_id)

WHERE computers.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.ID user_id,
       u.name user_name
       p.id,
       p.name,
       h.id,
       h.name
from USERS u join COMPUTERS c
on u.id=c.USER_ID
join PROCESSORS p
on c.id=p.id
join HARDDRIVES h
on c.id=h.id
where u.id=1
```